# Node.JS - Bcrypt returns "password false" even though password is correct

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, bcrypt

I am having some issues with my little project here. The issue I am having is that when I try to login through a post request, it returns password invalid! Even though I am 100% sure the password is the same, as the password is: "password".

I have been at it now for a while, but cant seem to get anything to work. I have been comparing the two hashed password (the one I have in mongoDB and the one that is being compared in my code), and its exactly the same!

Here is some code:

**User.js (model)**

```
// imports

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

userSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    return next();
  }

  bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    this.password = hash;
    next();
  });
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

**login.js**

```
// imports

const router = express.Router();

const JWT_SECRET = "test";

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid User credentials" });
    }

    console.log("Hashed Password from DB:", user.password);
    console.log("Password from Request:", password);

    const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(
      password.trim(),
      user.password.trim()
    );

    console.log("Password Valid?", isPasswordValid);

    if (!isPasswordValid) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid Password credentials" });
    }

    const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: "1h" });
    res.json({ token });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("An error occurred:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "An error occurred" });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

**register.js**

```
    // imports
    router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
      const { username, password } = req.body;
    
      try {
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ username });
        if (existingUser) {
          return res.status(400).json({ error: "Username already exists" });
        }
    
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
        const newUser = new User({
          username,
          password: hashedPassword,
        });
    
        await newUser.save();
        res.json({ message: "User registered successfully" });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: "An error occurred" });
      }
    });

module.exports = router;
```

**Server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const loginRouter = require("./login");
const registerRouter = require("./register");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

// mongoose connection

// Login Route Files
app.use("/login", loginRouter);
app.use("/register", registerRouter);

// Route Files
...

// User imported route files
...

const PORT = 5020;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started, port: ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: you have used bcrypt in `pre hooks` in mongoose ODM schema and `again you are hashing in register.js`. isn't it `two times hashing?` i think this may be the reason for your error